# C# blocking selecting treenode

Tags: c#, treeview

How can i block selecting a node from treeview?
I tried to use isselected, but it doesn't work.

```
                          TreeNode node_serie = node_bad.Nodes.Add
                                (lab_ser.Text);

                            node_serie.Tag = k;

                            node_serie.IsSelected = false;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are looking for?  Do you want to prevent the node from being selected?  Are you using winforms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, etc.?  Can you post some code showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

In WinForms, handle the [`BeforeSelect` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx) and set `e.Cancel` to `true`.